# Can I have multiple simultaneous connections open?

Tags: java, mongodb

Can I open several Mongo connections simultaneously from the same thread, or is it preferable to open just one connection and use it for all my calls?

Answer (score 0):

Java MongoDB Driver maintains an internal connection pool, you should get a connection from `MongoClient` and then close it once you are done with it. MongoClient is thread safe, so you can use it easily in multi-threaded environment.

Quick sample code shown below.

```
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongo.getDB("test");

    DBCollection col = db.getCollection("users");
    //Some operations

    //close resources
    mongo.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-concurrency/#java-driver-concurrency), you'll see that you'll be using a connection pool whether you want it or not, with a default maximum size of 100.

So to answer your question: use a single `MongoClient` across all threads, but bear in mind that this does not equate to a single MongoDB connection.